rational section non vanishing everywhere at any irreduicble component implies regular?
Let $X$ be a locally Notherian and reduced scheme, $\mathscr{L}$ be an invertible sheaf on it and $s$ be a rational section on $\mathscr{L}$. Suppose $s$ is not vanishing everywhere at any irreducible component of $X$, i.e., the locus set of $s$ does not contain any irreduicble component of $X$. (As defined in Why does a globally generated invertible sheaf admit a global section not vanishing on any irreducible component?)
Then is $s$ a regular rational section? That’s, for any point $x$ where $s$ is defined, $s_x$  is a regular element in $\mathscr{L}_x$, as Görtz&Wedhorn’s definition:

Definition and Remark 11.22. Let $X$ be a scheme and let $\mathscr{F}$ be a quasi-coherent $\mathscr{O}_X$-module. Then a section $s \in \Gamma(X, \mathscr{F})$ is called regular if the following equivalent assertions hold.
(i) The homomorphism of $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules $\mathscr{O}_X \rightarrow \mathscr{F}, f \mapsto f s$, is injective.
(ii) For all $x \in X$ the image of $s$ in $\mathscr{F}_x$ is a regular element of the $\mathscr{O}_{X, x}$-module $\mathscr{F}_x$.
(iii) For any open affine $U=\operatorname{Spec} A \subseteq X$, the restriction $f_{\mid U}$ is a regular element of the $A$-module $\Gamma(U, \mathscr{F})$.

If $X$ is integral then I see it’s true for being regular and nonzero is equivalent. But the case assuming $X$ Noetherian and reduced I am stuck someway not clear, and not sure if Noetherian is a necessary condition or not.
I (maybe, not sure) got one direction but not sure if it’s correct:

If $S$ is not regular in W&G’s sense then these is some $x$ such that $s_x$ is not regular in $\mathscr{L}_x$. Hence there is some $f_x$ in $\mathscr{O}_x$ such that $f_x s_x \neq 0$ with $f_x \neq 0$. Hence there is some open set $U$ about $x$ such that $f s=0$ (Here it requires locally Noetherian?) and hence $s$ vanishes everywhere at $D(f)$. Now $f \neq 0$ and since $X$ is reduced, $D(f) \neq \varnothing$. Hence $D(f)$ intersects some irreducible component $Z$ and $s$ must vanish everywhere at $Z$

This question comes from a setup in Vakil’s FOAG, section 15.4.2 discussing Weil divisors. And the word “regular” used by Vakil seems meaning that $s$ is (Vakil’s) regular at a point $x$ if $x$ is contained in this maximal domain of definition (or equivalently, if there is some open set containing $x$ where $s$ is defined) (don’t need to be a nonzero divisor) and hence I add the word “W&G’s” before regular to avoid confusion.

@BrianNugent that looks like an answer to me - would you consider recording that below?

@BrianNugent Thanks! it’s very elegant

By working locally, we may assume $\mathcal{L}$ is $\mathcal{O}_X$ and that $X$ is affine. If $s$ were not regular, it would have to be contained in an associated prime of $X$ as the union of the associated primes is the set of all zerodivisors. Since $X$ is reduced, the associated primes are the same as the minimal primes which correspond to the irreducible components of $X$. So if $s$ is not regular, it must vanish on some irreducible component.
